# Reformulation of Russell's Paradox?

Tags: logic, set-theory

Imagine the set D of all logical propositions that are true if and only if they are false.

Is it proven that this is the same thing as the set of all sets that are not members of themselves?

Could there possibly be a logical proposition which is true iff it's false, even if we don't allow sets to be self-referential?

Edit:

From a naive view, it looks like the claim is that it should be impossible to construct a statement that negates itself.

So for example, the set D1 of all sets that are not members of themselves apart from D1, but D1 is not a member of itself, is a perfectly acceptable set.

And the set D2 of all sets that are not members of themselves apart from D2, and also contains D2 as a member, is another perfectly acceptable set. We can do whatever logic we like on both of those sets.

The problem only comes if we are allowed to state "the set of all sets that are not members of themselves" and use that without qualification. The problem is that we can say that, and then when we say it we are troubled.

I can define a square circle as a circle that has no corners and also has four corners. This is a paradox because if it has no corners then it can't have four corners, and vice versa. But there is no real problem here because there are no square circles to trouble me. I can make up all the bad definitions I want, and nobody will care.

But they do care about the set that's a member of itself iff it is not a member of itself.

Why is THIS paradoxical entity important when none of the others are important?

Why is the solution to the problem not merely to declare that statements which are true iff they are false are badly-formed statements that we will not perform logic on?

Comment: For the record, it's the set of all sets that are not *elements* of themselves. $A\subseteq A$ is true for all sets $A$.

Comment: Thank you, eyeballfrog. I said that wrong.

Comment: It is not enough to declare certain statements are "badly-formed statements that we will not perform logic on". We must have a rule to determine which statements are well-formed statements, otherwise, when we write down a statement, we do not know whether it is legitimate or not. The point of Russell's paradox is to highlight a need for such a rule - if "the set of all sets x such that x is not an element of x" causes a problem, how do we know what other statements might cause a problem?

Comment: It was important because unlike a square circle, there were seemingly compelling reasons for the existence of the Russell set (its definition seemed consistent with ordinary mathematical reasoning ).

Comment: @Ted That makes sense. We'd like a rule to decide which statements are well-formed. If we can't find one, then we'd have to lump it, right? 

We know that sets that are or aren't members of themselves might be a problem. Do we know that nothing else is a problem? How do we know what other statements might cause a problem?

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen But it turned out that the definition was not consistent with itself. You could define the set either way without problems. The set without itself as a member or with itself as a member were both fine. Both Russel sets exist. The problem was only with using that particular way to define it.

Comment: The reason this paradox matters, is because unlike with the square circle, people thought that the Axiom of Unrestricted Comphrehension was a good axiom. Bertrand's Paradox shows otherwise. i.e. The Paradox was surprising, people didnt think it was possible to construct such a contradictory set.

Comment: Maybe I'm just naive. It sounds like they tried to write an axiom that said there can't be a self-contradictory statement, when they knew there are self-contradictory statements. Then they found one that impressed them and they made a big deal about it. And they still don't have a proof there can't be a self-contradictory statement even after they tried to make rules to keep them from stating that one.

Answer (score 1):

Russell’s Paradox tells us that unrestricted comprehension is not a principle that is suitable for set theory. Unrestricted comprehension was an axiom of Frege’s set theory that allows one to assert the existence of a set containing all and only the objects that have some well-defined property $\varphi$. Russell realized that this principle is inconsistent with first-order reasoning. That is, let $\varphi(x)=x \not \in x$. Then, Frege’s unrestricted comprehension gives us a set $A$ that must contain itself, but cannot. If $A$ doesn’t contain itself, then it satisfies $\varphi$ and must be a member of itself. If $A$ contains itself, then it must not contain itself, since members of $A$ don’t contain themselves.

More generally, Russell’s Paradox exemplifies the first-order theorem $\forall x \exists y (Rxy \iff Ryy)$, for an arbitrary two-place predicate “$R$”. Frege’s original axiom yields a formula logically equivalent to the the negation of this theorem where “$R$” is defined as “$\in$”, namely $\exists x \forall y (Rxy \iff \neg Ryy)$.

Comment: Thank you, @Pdubya_24. I'm not completely sure I understand what you're saying. It looks like you're saying that Russell's paradox is an *example* of a statement that contradicts itself, and that Frege's axiom says that should not be possible.

Comment: Not exactly. What I’m saying is that Russell demonstrated that Frege’s axiom of comprehension was inconsistent since it asserts the existence of a set that is defined in a way that defies the theorem of FOL mentioned in my answer.